# Why am I getting Boot\BCD error when booting a windows installation USB?

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, bios

I've tried creating a windows 8 and 7 installation medias from Ubuntu 16.04 using

- WoeUSB
- UNetBootIn
- GParted

In all the above cases I got the Boot\BCD error. Error code was 0xc000000e.

The BIOS supports only legacy boot, motherboard P5RD2-VM.

I've used MBR with FAT32 partition.

Not only that, I've used a windows PC to create the bootable media using PowerISO. The problem persists.

The media booted fine when tested on my friend's newer Computer. It supports UEFI.

So recently, I've used WoeUSB to flash the ISO directly into an HDD partition.
When flashing Win 8, it booted to the logo, and then some flashing hex numbers appeared and pc rebooted.

In case of Win 7, the mouse pointer appeared on a black screen and that was it.

PS: I've had no problem booting from disks for windows installation, nor USBs for linux installation. Unfortunately, the DVD reader has died.

Comment: Also asked here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332395/why-is-windows-installation-media-giving-boot-bcd-error#comment2272619_1332395

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332395/why-is-windows-installation-media-giving-boot-bcd-error#comment2272618_1332395

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332395/why-is-windows-installation-media-giving-boot-bcd-error#comment2272619_1332395